# manage the "previous " button of the browser in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a cakePHP application. when the user is disconnected and the login page is displayed, if the user click on the back button of the browser, the previous page is always displayed. how to disable it in cakephp ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app/Config/core.php` uncomment line 158, that will give you this:

```
Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
```

Then in your controller function put this:

```
$this->disableCache();
```

E.g:

```
public function pageName(){
 $this->disableCache();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent that then you can disable caching by placing this on your AppController

2.X:

```
$this->response->disableCache();
```

3.X:

```
Cache::disable();
```

Comment: Thanks Iwillscoop.  but the server send me an error because the syntax Cache::disable() is not correct. so i used  $this->disableCache(); and its work fine.